# Купить две книги

Tags: падежи

Как доказать, что слово "книги" в данном случае употреблено в именительном падеже?

Answer (score 3):

> ***Купить две книги.***
>
> Как доказать, что слово "книги" в данном случае употреблено в форме
>   именительного падежа?

Никак не докажете. Потому что  слово ***книги*** в Вашем примере стоит в форме **родительного** падежа **единственного** числа.

Само количественно-именное сочетание ***две книги*** стоит в форме **винительного** падежа: *купить* (**что?**  – вопрос В. падежа) *две книги*.

Имя числительное ***две*** употреблено в форме **винительного** (совпадающей с формой **именительного**) падежа.

Зависимое слово в сочетании ***две книги*** – существительное ***книги***  –  имеет форму **родительного** падежа **ед. ч.**

Из [***Чеснокова Л. Д. "Имя числительное в современном русском языке. Семантика. Грамматика. Функции", Ростов н/Д, 1997***]:

> Если имя числительное употреблено в форме И. и В. (В = И) падежей, то
>   зависимое имя существительное **обязательно имеет форму родительного
>   падежа**…
>
> В именительном и винительном падежах (В = И) при числительных ***два,
>   три, четыре*** и в составных числительных с последним сегментом
>   ***два, три, четыре*** зависимое существительное употребляется только в форме **единственного** числа, а при числительных ***пять*** и выше
>    – только в форме **множественного** числа. В косвенных падежах имена
>   существительные имеют только форму **множественного** числа: *два
>   дуба, двух **дубов…***

Comment: Alex_ander пишет: две книги могут...

Comment: _**shampar**:  Alex_ander пишет: две книги могут_... === Ну так в этом примере в именительном падеже стоит только само сочетание "две книги". Существительное же "книги" внутри количественно-именного сочетания стоит в родительном падеже.

Comment: Абсолютно верно, количественно-именные сочетания  начиная с двух в им. и вин. пад. связаны с помощью управления,главное слово числительное управляет родительным падежом существительного, в других падежах будет согласование - одинаковое изменение обоих слов : двух книг, двум книгам, двумя книгами, о двух книгах.

Comment: Это слитное сочетание.Купить что? две книги, всё сочетание является дополнением в винительном падеже. Две книги привлекли моё внимание. Две книги - подлежащее, сочетание в им. пад.Падеж определяется по главному слову в сочетании. Но так делается только в начальной школе, а дальше говорится: дополнение выражено слитным сочетанием числительного две  в вин. пад. и сущ. книги в род. пад.

Answer (score 0):

Есть только один способ это доказать: привести полное предложение.

> Купить две книги могут внимание читателя:
>
> Их по цене одной такой он купит обязательно.

И если "две книги" объявить единой сущностью.

Comment: Я с Вами полностью согласна. Но это тестовое задание. Контекст привели полный. Ответ: в. п. Учитель именно этого мнения и придерживается, а я считаю, что тут двояко можно рассмотреть данное задание. Именно поэтому и должно быть какое-то объяснению. Может метод "подмены" использовать? Купить две коровы (например). В данном случае "коровы" употреблено во мн.ч. в им.п. (в в.п. было бы "коров"). Или мои рассуждения не являются верными?

Answer (score 0):

Я отвечаю на тот вопрос, который был поставлен изначально. Не знаю, зачем его поправили.

> Как доказать, что слово "книги" в данном случае употреблено в форме
>   именительного падежа? И почему?

Слово "книги" здесь стоит в родительном падеже единственного числа.
**Форма** его **совпадает** с именительным множественного, но не является им.

Сочетание "две книги"  - в винительном падеже. Никак не именительный, это именно совпадающие формы. В именительном тут только местоимение "я".

> что тут двояко можно рассмотреть данное задание

Каким образом, поясните.

> В данном случае "коровы" употреблено во мн.ч. в им.п. (в в.п. было бы
>   "коров"). Или мои рассуждения не являются верными?

Нет, это тоже родительный падеж. Замените на "купить два альбома" - именительным, да еще множественным, даже не пахнет.
Вопрос ваш очень простой, никакой "подмены" не требует.

Можно, конечно, рассуждать на тему, откуда здесь родительный падеж **единственного** числа. Он образовался тут в результате длительных грамматических изменений в силу распада  так называемого двойственного числа и оформления числительного как самостоятельной части речи. Ранее числительные один, два, три и четыре грамматически были эквивалентны существительным (Если совсем примитивно, сравните "брата книги" вот он, родительный, раньше подобное имело место и в сочетании с нынешними числительными). Но это уже древняя историческая грамматика, в школьную программу не входит, да и не актуально для современного языка.